# How to avoid space between two div's with bootstrap class?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap I created two div's, in the output it coming one by one, but between two div's extra space is coming how to remove this space with bootstrap class. I have to do it by not using margin and padding.

This is my code index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="one">
                    <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    <h1>World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is main.css

```
.one {
    background: red;
}

.two {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Use `.mt-0` to remove the marging in the top, if it's padding what is causing the space use `.pt-0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `p-0 or m-0` class in both the divs you want to remove the space between if it is not satisfactory read this document on  [Bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `div` to be invisible, use `d-none`  property of Bootstrap. There is no other way making a div invisible without using margin or padding as you mentioned in your question.